# Display the complete json data from API response in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, rest

I'm getting the json data from the API call but its not displaying the complete data.There are a lot of properties to work with and creating the model would be difficult as it's my first time working on any API.So i wanted to use app.quicktype.io to parse the json data directly into dart code for which i need to get the complete json data.Right now only little bit of the json data is being displayed in the console.

CODE:

```
Future<void> getContacts() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    String contacts_url =
        'https://mylinkexample.com';
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic mykeyexampele';
    var response = await client.get(contacts_url,
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
    var jsonString = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(jsonString);
  }
```

Comment: Did you verify through POSTMAN or directly that the response from the backend brings all the information ?, because it could be that it is not bringing all the information from the backend.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the output and how it sould look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```dart
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

test() {
  developer.log(response.body);
}
```